# Determine if my laptop can handle certain resolution

Tags: laptop, resolution, external-display

I have a Dell Latitude E6510 and thinking of buying an external monitor with a resolution of 2560 x 1600.

Is there any tool I can use to determine if my laptop will be able to use the full resolution of the monitor?

I'm using Ubuntu. `lspci` shows

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [NVS 3100M] (rev a2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported resolution depends amongst others on what interface you use.

The dell datesheet shows the graphics adapter [NVIDIA® NVS 3100M 512MB tec specification](http://www.nvidia.de/object/nvs_techspecs.html)

```
VGA analog display support = Up to 2048x1536
DisplayPort multimode = Up to 2560x1600
HDMI support = Up to 1920x1080
```

**Edit**
Depending on the graphics apater memory and the colour depth you want to use, there could be calculated a theoretical maximum.

But the resolution of each interface (as you see, three different resolutions) depends on the used internal hardware. I'm not sure but I think there is no way for a general tool to get out the max effective resolution.

Comment: Wow, cool. Thanks for the info! Is there a way to figure this out info directly? IIRC there's some command called eide?

Comment: See edit, and  .... Merry Christmas!

Comment: Thanks! Merry Christmas to you too :) (Now I'm going to do some christmas shopping for myself ;-)